# Visibility feature is not working on Text view

Tags: android, textview

What i have is two text view and what i want to do is when one of them is selected or focused , i want the other one to be invisible or disabled and i have tried many ways but none of them have worked , i don't know why ! here is my xml code :

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative1"
                android:background="@drawable/down"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                 android:focusable="true" >

   <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
                           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          />
  <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/txtsearch2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And here is my java code :

```
  if(textView.isFocused()==true){// txtsearch
                            textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//txtsearch2
                            active=1;
                        }else {
                            textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            active=2;
                        }
```

And also i have tried `isSelected` and it didn't work , can anyone help me?

Comment: where is textView2 textView ? try if(**txtsearch**.isFocused()==true)

Comment: it's the same textView is txtsearch and textView2 is textsearch2

Comment: show us some more code around (is this in focusChangedListener, TouchListener, clickeListener?)

Comment: where this functionality used?

Comment: no i made it on create .. it won't work?? because i want it to work when the user start to write on any one of the textviews

Comment: how can i add on focus change listener and where shall i add to the relative layout or to something else?

Comment: at that time only one textview will be focused ,so what you will be tried.i can't understand your logic

Comment: it worked on focusChangedListener .. can you make it as an answer so i can vote it?? @LubosHoracek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add onFocusChangeListener to your textViews,

```
tv1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.onFocusChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
                tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
tv2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.onFocusChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
               tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

tv1 and tv2 is your textViews.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could simplify the condition logic. There is no need to compare the result of isFocused() with *true*. You could just write `if(textView.isFocused()){...}`.

But you still have to use listeners so whenever one TextView gains focus, the other one will change its visibility. Here is an example:

```
        textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        textView2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

If you rather need an onClickListener (I believe you do), here is a sample for that:

```
        textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To react to focusing your views use FocusChangeListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html